# Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/diagnostics/loggers in Azure API Manager - Azure bicep

Tags: azure-bicep

I'm trying to deploy Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/diagnostics/loggers with the help of bicep.
I saw that there is no documentation from microsoft on it at all. [Screenshot of resource im trying to deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwEee.png)
In bicep the newest API version is 2018-01-01. If i try to deploy i get this error: [Error message when trying to test deploy with existing resources, application insight and workspace.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stiP4.png)

Is that resource deprecated? Is it implemented into diagnostics itself? If so. How does it work when loggerID is required when deploying diagnostics?

Ive tried deploying it X-number of times and it always fails with the error that the API version is outdated even if 2018 is the newest, and it "requires" 2021 or newer.

Comment: the error message is telling you api version 2018-01-01 is not supported anymore, have you tried one of the api version from the error message ?

Comment: Have you tried with the latest versions? Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/apis/diagnostics?pivots=deployment-language-bicep). @gouss4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possibility of using resource provider [`Diagnostics/loggers`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/main/specification/apimanagement/resource-manager/Microsoft.ApiManagement/stable/2018-01-01/apimdiagnostics.json) is working with only `2018-01-01` Api version.

After that, it got deprecated and added the `logger id` property directly under
[`Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/diagnostics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/apis/diagnostics?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) resource itself. Hence, you need to use this specific resource to enable or retrieve logger related details.

Reference [document](https://vinniejames.medium.com/bicep-automate-deployment-of-api-management-and-its-components-26e4b8aee28) for more relevant information including bicep code.

*I tried below bicep code in my environment to meet your requirement and was able to deploy it successfully as shown below.*

```bash
param apimname string = 'policyj'
param apiname string = 'newjapis'
resource apim 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2023-03-01-preview' existing = {
name : apimname
}
 resource apiManagementServiceapi 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2021-08-01' = {
  parent: apim
  name: apiname
  properties: {
    displayName: apiname
    apiRevision: '1'
    subscriptionRequired: true
    path: apiname
    protocols: [
      'https'
    ] 
  }
}
resource appInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02-preview' existing = {
  name: 'newsigh'
}
resource apiManagementLogging 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/loggers@2021-08-01'={
  name: 'newloger'
  parent: apim
  properties:{
    loggerType:'applicationInsights'
    description:'APIM Logger resources'
    credentials: {
      instrumentationKey: appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
    }
  }
}
resource apiManagementApids 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/diagnostics@2023-03-01-preview'={
  name:'applicationinsights'
  parent:apiManagementServiceapi
  properties:{
    loggerId:apiManagementLogging.id
    alwaysLog:'allErrors'
    verbosity:'error'
  }
}
```

*Deployment succeeded:*

[image]

[image]

*Note*: If you want to retrieve the `logger Id` value, use [`Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/outputs?tabs=azure-powershell#define-output-values) field in bicep.